# javascript value before @ sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to suggest username for sign up page with jquery. im just wondering how can i get the value of email address before `@` sign. right now i can get complete value with

```
$("#email").val();
```

should i split it by `@` or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can split a string using the split prototype function like so:

```
var Email = $("email").val();

var Suggestion = Email.split("@")[0]; // [0] for the first portion of the string.
```

@Resource : http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php

as this is a prototype of the string it can be used on any string like so:

```
var world = "Hello World".split(" ")[0];
```

regardless weather its set to a variable, or the value has come from a function, you would also be able to directly run after the `val()` method as it returns a string.

```
$("#email").val().split("@")[0]
//---------------^ String is returned here.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var local = $('#email').val().split('@')[0];
//alert(local)
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting by "@" it's perfect, if the email address is valid (ex. it match a regexp). It's not allowed more than one time in the address, so you are on the safe side. You can find more information on this topic [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: This was not really the answer that is required therefore it should of been a comment.

Comment: @RobertPitt why do you say it's not the answer required? From his question he says:"should i split it by @ or some other way?" so it seems to be aware of the javascript split() method, and I've interpreted the question as a way to know if there are better ways than split() or if split() is ok for his use-case

Comment: All i was saying is the question was specifically about splitting the string by the `@` symbol and not about sanitation or validation. you answer is good but it just belongs as a comment I think.

Comment: @RoberPitt ok I understand your point, thank you for commenting!